# Nao consigo mostrar o Dicionario todo no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

olá. quando dou um Print no dicionario alunos só mostrar o ultimo valor adicionado e nao todos que adicionei por meio do input.
no caso so mostrar por ex: {'nome': 'david', 'media': 5.0, 'Situacao': 'Reprovado'}
mais eu adicionei 3 vezes e so mostrar a ultima.

alunos = {}
lista = []

for  i in range (1,4):

```
alunos['nome'] = input("Digite seu Nome: ")
alunos['media'] = float(input("Digite Sua Media: "))
alunos['Situacao'] = 'aprovado'

lista.append(alunos.copy())
alunos = dict(alunos)
if alunos['media'] < 7.0:
    alunos.update({'Situacao' : 'Reprovado'})
    print(f"o Nome é {alunos['nome']} \nSua media é {alunos['media']} \nSituação é igual {alunos['Situacao']}\n\n")
    
else:
    alunos.update({'Situacao' :'Aprovado'})
    print(f"o Nome é {alunos['nome']} \nSua media é {alunos['media']} \nSituação é igual {alunos['Situacao']}\n\n")
    alunos.update()
```

print(lista)
print(alunos)

for elem in lista:

```
print(list(elem.keys())[0])
print(elem[list(elem.keys())[0]])
```

Comment: Acho que vc está complicando à toa. Se quer uma lista de dicionários, simplesmente crie um novo dicionário a cada iteração e adicione-o na lista (em vez de ficar criando cópias e fazendo `update`), algo assim: https://ideone.com/KFfdvV

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Tens que usar chaves para inserir vários elementos no mesmo dicionário. Podes usar o nome como chave e depois criar um dicionário dentro dessa chave.

```
alunos = {} 
lista = []

for i in range (1,4):

    nome = input("Digite seu Nome: ")
    alunos[nome] = {}
    alunos[nome]['nome'] = nome
    alunos[nome]['media'] = float(input("Digite Sua Media: "))
    alunos[nome]['Situacao'] = 'aprovado'

    lista.append(alunos[nome].copy())
    if alunos[nome]['media'] < 7.0:
        alunos[nome].update({'Situacao' : 'Reprovado'})
        print(f"o Nome é {alunos[nome]['nome']} \nSua media é {alunos[nome]['media']} \nSituação é igual {alunos[nome]['Situacao']}\n\n")
    else:
        alunos[nome].update({'Situacao' :'Aprovado'})
        print(f"o Nome é {alunos[nome]['nome']} \nSua media é {alunos[nome]['media']} \nSituação é igual {alunos[nome]['Situacao']}\n\n")
        alunos[nome].update()

print(lista) 
print(alunos)

for elem in lista:
    print(list(elem.keys())[0])
    print(elem[list(elem.keys())[0]])
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!